# Laravel issue when compare times - date format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause, php-carbon

I have at Maxoffer model:

```
protected $dates = [
        'start'
    ];

    public function setStartAttribute($date){
        $this->attributes['start']= Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i a', $date);
    }
    public function getStartAttribute($date){
        return (new Carbon($date))->toRfc2822String();
    }
```

In my database `start` is stored in format: 2016-02-02 00:00:00 [image]

Now when I try to run `WHERE` query:

```
$maxoffer =  Maxoffer::where('article_id', $request->input('article_id'))
                    ->where('start', $request->input('start'))
                    ->first();
dd($maxoffer);
```

`Input(start)` is in format: 2016-02-02 12:00 am also i try to make it in this format: 2016-02-02 00:00:00 but again dont work so dd give me result `null`
I got a problem becouse I dont know how to compare start and input(start). How to make them at same format...

Also I cant change:

```
public function getStartAttribute($date){
            return (new Carbon($date))->toRfc2822String();
        }
```

becouse I need it at this format for other thing.

So how to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below where the string is converted into Carbon time and Eloquent then can compare the times in DB

```
->where('start', Carbon::parse($request->input('start')))
```